# How do I use standard object Validation Rules in a Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, validation-rule

I'm still learning how to use Lightning Components and would appreciate help. I have several Validation Rules on a child object. There is an action on the parent object which uses a Lightning Component, which is to create this child object. If Save is clicked on the component and it fails the validation rules, it displays the error message behind the popup window, instead of on the component. 
[image]

Can a Lightning Component use object Validation Rules? If so, how? If not, what do I need to do please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ***apex*** to save the record, you can use try-catch block to get the exception, and then sending it to aura back where you can show the error properly. Something like
in apex:

```
try {
    insert/update record;
    return new ResponseWrapper(true, null);
} catch (DMLException dmle) {
    return new ResponseWrapper(false, dmle.getDmlMessage());
}
```

ResponseWrapper is a wrapper class you can use to send the messages with Boolean **success** and String **message** parameters. (Or may be you can send string directly if you are just trying.)
Then in lightning component js callback method parameter (lets say response) you can write:

```
var message = response.getReturnValue().message;
```

If you are using ***lightning data service*** to save the record, there is a callback for example in this code sample-

```
component.find("opportunityRecordCreator").saveRecord(function(saveResult) {

})
```

**saveResult** is a variable where you can access state, success and error property accordingly as per your requirement.